# iPhone using voiceover moves off screen, cannot press button

Tags: iphone, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

I have run into a baffling behavior using VoiceOver. Basically when using the "swipe forward" gesture on a screen, the cursor will run off the bottom of the screen and the view will not "move" with it as it should. Worse of all, I have a button down there that is not activated by a double tap when this behavior exists.

What I can gather is that this only seems to happen on two screens, both of which feature customized appearances of the cells in a table view.

I have tried manipulating the `accessibilityFrame` property of these cells and these table views. I have gotten nowhere. I have tried setting the `accessibilityFrame` property of the cells as they are made but there was no change in behavior.

Has anyone encountered this behavior? Any ideas for trying to tackle this problem?

Comment: If the element isn't supposed to be reachable while being off-screen you can set it to not be an accessibility element when it moves-off screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it, but it's not a problem, at least not in my app -- you can double-tap anywhere, not just on the button. (In other words, a blind user won't realize this is going on, because it just works.)